# How to return structure array in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, structure

So I've been trying to implement Kruskal's algorithm, first I want to make clear the question is not related to the implementation of the algorithm. I've created one `graph.hpp` file, one `kruskalsAlgo.hpp` and `main.cpp` as follows respectively:

```
#pragma once

struct Edge
{
    int source;
    int destination;
    int weight;
};

struct Graph
{
    int V;
    int E;

    Edge* edge;
};

Graph* create_graph(int V, int E)
{
    Graph* graph = new Graph;
    graph -> V = V;
    graph -> E = E;

    graph -> edge = new Edge[E];

    return graph;
}
```

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <tuple>

#include "../Graph/Graph.hpp"

class Kruskals_Algo
{
    private:
        struct subset
        {
            int parent;
            int rank;
        };

        void make_set(subset*, int);
        int find_set(subset*, int);
        void _union(subset*, int, int);
    
    public:
        Edge* kruskal(Graph*);
        void print_kruskals_MST(Edge*, int);
};

void Kruskals_Algo::make_set(subset* subsets, int V)
{
    subsets[V].parent = V;
    subsets[V].rank = 0;
}

int Kruskals_Algo::find_set(subset* subsets, int V)
{
    if(subsets[V].parent != V)
        subsets[V].parent = find_set(subsets, subsets[V].parent);
    
    return subsets[V].parent;
}

void Kruskals_Algo::_union(subset* subsets, int x, int y)
{
    int xroot = find_set(subsets, x);
    int yroot = find_set(subsets, y);

    if(subsets[xroot].rank < subsets[yroot].rank)
        subsets[xroot].parent = yroot;
    
    else if(subsets[xroot].rank > subsets[yroot].rank)
        subsets[yroot].parent = xroot;

    else
    {
        subsets[yroot].parent = xroot;
        subsets[xroot].rank++;
    }
}

inline int myComp(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    Edge* a1 = (Edge*)a;
    Edge* b1 = (Edge*)b;
    return a1 -> weight > b1 -> weight;
}

Edge* Kruskals_Algo::kruskal(Graph* graph)
{
    int V = graph -> V;
    Edge result[V];
    Edge* result_ptr = result;
    int e = 0;
    int i = 0;

    qsort(graph -> edge, graph -> E, sizeof(graph -> edge[0]), myComp);

    subset* subsets = new subset[(V * sizeof(subset))];

    for (int v = 0; v < V; ++v)
        make_set(subsets, v);

    while(e < V - 1 && i < graph -> E)
    {
        Edge next_edge = graph -> edge[i++];

        int x = find_set(subsets, next_edge.source);
        int y = find_set(subsets, next_edge.destination);

        if (x != y)
        {
            result[e++] = next_edge;
            _union(subsets, x, y);
        }
    }
    //return std::make_tuple(res, e);
    return result_ptr;
}

void Kruskals_Algo::print_kruskals_MST(Edge* r, int e)
{
    int minimumCost = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<e; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << r[i].source << " -- "
                  << r[i].destination << " == "
                  << r[i].weight << std::endl;
        minimumCost = minimumCost + r[i].weight;
    }
    
    std::cout << "Minimum Cost Spanning Tree: " << minimumCost << std::endl;
}
```

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Graph/Graph.hpp"

#include "Kruskals_Algo/kruskalsAlgo.hpp"
//#include "Prims_Algo/primsAlgo.hpp"

using namespace std;

class GreedyAlgos
{        
    public:
        void kruskals_mst();
        //void prims_mst();
};

void GreedyAlgos::kruskals_mst()
{
    Kruskals_Algo kr;
    int V;
    int E;
    int source, destination, weight;
    
    cout << "\nEnter the number of vertices: ";
    cin >> V;
    cout << "\nEnter the number of edges: ";
    cin >> E;
    
    Edge* res;

    Graph* graph = create_graph(V, E);

    for(int i=0; i<E; i++)
    {
        cout << "\nEnter source, destinstion and weight: ";
        cin >> source >> destination >> weight;
        graph -> edge[i].source = source;
        graph -> edge[i].destination = destination;
        graph -> edge[i].weight = weight;
    }

    //std::tie(result, E) = kr.kruskal(graph);
    res = kr.kruskal(graph);
    kr.print_kruskals_MST(res, E);
}

int main()
{
    int choice;
    GreedyAlgos greedy;
    greedy.kruskals_mst();
    
    return 0;
}
```

So my question here is when I debug the program the values in `Edge result[V]`, which is a structure array, are calculated correctly, at position `[0] [1] [2]` as in the following picture:

[image]

but when the function `print_kruskals_MST(res, E)` is called from the main the values printed are different:

[image]

Is there any pointer thing that I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!
P.S. Ignore the comments!

Comment: Don't use an array, use a `std::vector`.

Comment: Marginally related: `new subset[(V * sizeof(subset))]` is rather suspicious. What's the `sizeof` for? `new` is not `malloc`, and `new subset[V]` will already allocate the right amount for `V` entries of type `subset`.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, one line at a time, and inspect the values of all objects, variables, and pointers, what did you see?

Answer (score 1):

This answer might not answer your question directly but it should shed some light on the problem.

First of all, yes you have a lot of pointer problems...

Secondly, pair ANY use of the `new` operator with the `delete` operator. As it stands, you have a bunch of memory leaks.

Also, why `create_graph`? Create a constructor for `Graph` instead (and a destructor since the class has an `Edge* edge` it needs to take care of).

```
struct Graph
{
    int V;
    int E;

    Edge* edge;

    // constructor
    Graph(int V, int E)
    {
        this->V = V;
        this->E = E;
        this->edge = new Edge[E];
    }

    // destructor
    ~Graph()
    {
        // nullify the member variable before deleting its memory is just a safety measure pertaining to multithreading.
        Edge* _edge = this->edge;
        this->edge = nullptr;
        delete _edge;
    }
};
```

Then change `Graph* graph = create_graph(V, E);` into `Graph* graph = new Graph(V, E);` and do `delete graph` when you're done using it.

Make sure you remove all memory leaks and we can go on to discussing referencing the correct data (f.ex. by me changing my answer).